# 「拝」から始まる謙譲語 -- humble keigo starting with [hai]

Tags: words, keigo

What are the common 謙譲語 verbs that start with 「拝」?  I know these ones:

> 見る　→　拝見する (to see), 拝観する (to view something -- limited usage)
>
> 聴く　→　拝聴する
>
> 読む　→　拝読する
>
> 会う　→　拝謁する (although I've never heard this used, and know that 目にかかる is more common)
>
> 借りる　
> →　拝借する

Are there any others that commonly used??  Actually, I've used **拝読** before but was later told that no one really uses it, and お読みする was more common.

Comment: Interesting that there's no 「拝会する」.

Comment: jisho.org gives you a list, but these are only used when you forget how to use 謙譲語

Comment: Make community wiki or close as "cannot be answered". http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/124

Comment: @rep, only moderators can make CW, he can't

Comment: Thus the comment. Hopefully one will see it.

Comment: @repecmp: done! (BTW, flagging the post is the quickest way to request CW for a question)

Answer (score 3):

「拝啓」 （はいけい）　is also quite common on writing letters.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say I was only looking for verbs.  Updated OP.

Comment: That's also a verb, means 「つつしんで申し上げる」

Comment: At least in the modern Japanese, 拝啓 is only used as an opening word of a letter and never used as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

WOW, I was surprised how much people study formal saying of polite, and I've NEVER used it. we use 拝 for 拝見　and 拝借 but for others, for example 拝聴, we use お聞きになる because it's easier to understand.

We don't usually use 拝読, instead we use 拝見.

For example:

"Could I read your letter?"  It's actually **read** but we use  拝見 which means **look**.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know who you refer to by *we*. I get the feeling you don't mean native Japanese in general, since you exclude older people [in an answer to another question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/how-would-a-native-ask-the-question-where-are-you-going-later/1495#149).

Comment: @Ento: I think by "we", @Hikari means "Japanese people in general". In which he is probably overstepping a little bit (the use of keigo is down to socio-professional situations and context, not the whole people of Japan). We'll chalk it up to beginner enthusiasm and encourage Hikari to read through the [meta site](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/) (as well as other people's answers), to get tips on the best way to contribute! (general tip: you should try to keep the main part of your answer factual, even if you add some subjective content at the end)

Comment: well if I say 'I' then it's like I use it and it sounds like not everyone uses it...  and I have no idea what was going on there so don't talk about it, and don't bring that subject to another question

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the thoughtful follow-up. I'm glad you're one of the moderators. @Hikari I apologize if my previous comment came off as offensive. Frankly, my first reaction was "we who?" - I think it's generally confusing to use "we" in an internet forum, where people don't know the identity or background of each other. Even here, it's not as clear-cut as "ask foreigners, and you will be answered by natives." (Thinking of the right angle to discuss this on meta..)

Comment: お聞きになる is *NOT* equivalent to 拝聴. お聞きする, or better 伺う.