# how would a native ask the question "Where are you going later?"

Tags: usage, translation, questions

After reading the 2 threads: [How to use へ (-e), に (-ni), まで (made) and の方 (no-hō) with destination and direction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-to-use-e-ni-made-and-no-h-with-destination-and-directi) and [When going somewhere, is there any difference between e (へ) and ni (に)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80/when-going-somewhere-is-there-any-difference-between-e-and-ni)

I would like to ask how would a native ask the question "Where are you going later?"

1) 後どこへ行くか？

2) 後どこまで？

3) ?

Context: john talking to mary 30 minutes before school ends.

Comment: Just a quick note on your title: this has been [discussed in meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/168/is-it-ok-if-we-have-an-option-to-indicate-something-along-the-lines-of-please-on/170#170) and current consensus is that we do not require that a question be answered "by a native"... In your particular case, I feel that you meant it more as a general "what's the correct way" than a native fluency requirement, in which case it is still rather redundant ("correct Japanese way" is implied for all questions here ;-)

Comment: @Dave: I took "native" to mean: the everyday way someone in Japan would say it" or simply colloquial usage. If I asked that question with that verbiage, that's how I would mean it. Actually, from what I've seen and heard, that's how most people who are learning a new language mean it. No matter the language, we all know that the textbook way of saying something isn't always the way someone would say it normally in their day-to-day. But just so you know, I do understand the point you were making. Just adding another perspective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'm not native, so I don't know if this disqualifies me from answering... ... But in the context of your question, I'd say この後（で）どこ{へ／に}行く？

Your #1 could work, but using just あと instead of このあと gives a sense of "later" later.  Adding the この solidifies the meaning of "after this", where "this" means being at school.  You wouldn't use まで unless John knows she is definitely going somewhere somewhat far away and is really interested/concerned with the details of the whole journey.  #3 is just a question mark and presumably means he is just looking at her with a stupified, questionable look on his face.  :)

Comment: Maybe they teach telepathy at that school...